# How can I eat in Creative in Minecraft 1.12.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to be able to eat in Creative Mode. Is there any way to do this with commands?

Comment: I think it works for golden apples.

Comment: The simple method is to issue `/gamemode survival` - it's not a cheat to switch modes in a creative world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to eat in creative mode in vanilla (unmodded) minecraft. The purpose of eating is to replenish your food bar, but you never need to do that in creative mode. That's also why you can't eat in survival with a full food bar: there's just no reason to. See: [Why can't players on creative mode be able to eat?](https://www.planetminecraft.com/blog/why-cant-players-on-creative-mode-be-able-to-eat/)

The one exception to this are golden apples and enchanted golden apples, solely because they serve a purpose beyond just filling up your food bar.

Comment: technically, in pe you *can* eat with a full food bar.

Comment: @Niffler the question is about Minecraft 1.12, which doesn't exist for PE.

Comment: ok nevermind. Are there any mods that allow eating in Creative?

Comment: @Duel I really doubt it, most people don't have a use for eating in Creative. This might be helpful, though: https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-mods/requests-ideas-for-mods/1316318-eating-in-creative-mode.

Comment: @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle : actually, some mods introduce food that can be eaten when your bar is already full. I suspect you could still eat these in creative mode.

Answer (score 0):

Depends. In Bedrock Edition (Pe,Xbox,ect.) You can eat in creative and peaceful if you've gotten the most recent update.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, there is no way at the moment. However, they might add one in the future